# How can add "double line spacing" to any output?

Tags: bash

I would like to take the output of a bash command (in this case grep) and insert a blank line every other line:

```
not
like
this ...

but

like

this!
```

Smart way to do it in bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `pr` from `coreutils`:

```
$ grep '' file | pr -Td
not

like

this ...
```

(note that this *does* double-space the final line - unlike, say, `sed '$!G'`). From `man pr`:

```
   -d, --double-space
          double space the output

   -T, --omit-pagination
          omit page headers and trailers, eliminate any pagination by form
          feeds set in input files
```

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to do this for text files.  The simplest is probably

```
$ sed G filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with a file like:

```
$ cat >file
not
like
this ...
```

sed will work:

```
$ sed 's/$/\n/' file
not

like

this ...
```

So will awk:

```
$ awk 1 ORS='\n\n' file
not

like

this ...
```

`1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line and `ORS='\n\n'` tells awk to separate output lines with not just one but two newlines.

#### More

A shorter sed command, as suggested by [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver), is:

```
sed '$!G' file
```

The `G` command appends a newline and the *hold space* to the end of the *pattern space*.  Since, by default, the hold space is empty, this has the effect of just adding an extra newline at the end of each line.  The prefix `$!` tells sed to do this on all lines *except* the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk version:

```
| awk '{print $0, "\n"}'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Test
10
20
30

Output
perl -pe "s/$/\n/" test 
10

20

30
```